# How to view file manually created by android java program

Tags: android, android-file

I have created a file using

```
` try {
            File myFile = new File("myfile");
            if (myFile.exists())
                myFile.delete();
            outputStream = openFileOutput("myfile", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            Log.d("MyServiceActivity", "file written");
            outputStream.write(User.getInstance().getUserId().getBytes());
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
`
```

How do i view the file created manually. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the file is saved with `Context.MODE_PRIVATE` it is into internal memory, if you dont have root you will be not able to see this file with your phone

The best aproach to view your file is to open `device monitor` or `Android monitor` that is place in your `Android Studio IDE`

[image]

> Note: run your app in debug mode to be able to see internal memory
>   directories and files !

Be sure to have your device pluged to your pc to run it

Happy coding

Comment: I did as you said. But I couldn't find the file in the File Explorer.

Comment: is under the folder data, and without root, is the only way to see the file you are creating

Comment: you will need to go to the data folder and after that you will need to enter into your package name, for example com.example.yourproject, and after that the files will be there